# FirebaseAuth.getInstance() returns null in FirebaseModule

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, dagger-2, android-mvp

I'm developing my application using Model-View-Presenter approach.
I'm also using Dagger2 and I've create this module:

```
@Module
public class FirebaseModule {


@Provides @Singleton
public DatabaseReference provideDatabaseReference(){
    return FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
}

@Provides
public FirebaseAuth provideFirebaseAuth(){
    return FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
}
}
```

and this is my model that could update the presenter:

```
public class FirebaseModel implements Model, FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener {

@Inject
FirebaseAuth auth;

Presenter presenter;
FirebaseUser user;

@Inject
public FirebaseModel(Presenter presenter) {
    this.presenter = presenter;

}


@Override
public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
    user = auth.getCurrentUser();
    presenter.updateUser(user);

}


@Override
public void loadUser() {

    auth.addAuthStateListener(this);
}
}
```

the problem is that the injection of

```
FirebaseAuth auth;
```

returns `NullPointerException`.
I've read that this getInstance() must be done in the `onCreate()` method of the `MainActivity`, but in this case it breaks the MVP approach because the view logic must be passive.

So how could I do in this case?

Thank you

Comment: What are you trying to do? Field or constructor injection? Currently you have an annotated field (`FirebaseAuth auth`) as well as an annotated constructor.

Comment: in this case I want to do a constructor injection but I need FirebaseAuth in this model so I've thought to inject this dependency..is it wrong?

Comment: Cosntructor injection means that you declare your dependencies in your constructor (not by annotating your fields) `@Inject FirebaseModel(Presenter presenter, FirebaseAuth auth)` to inject the constructor

Comment: so if I need to use constructor injection i could avoid @Inject and I could declare private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth?

Comment: constructor injection means dagger will call your constructor and pass the dependencies in. You can hide your fields and don't have to annotate them

Comment: so so I could add this line to the constructor: auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143892/discussion-between-ste9206-and-david-medenjak).